# Adding a second Map into a GoogleMaps-Map in GWT

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

Hi I am trying to put a second smaller map in a goole maps map.
It should show the same area as the maps centre, but the zoom level shoudl be lower i.e.
it should show a larger area.

I am working with GWT, and i have found one solution by adding a Second MapWidget to the existing MapWidget with "addControlWidget". But i haven't found a way to position this Widget, so its in the top left corner. I would like to be able to change the position.

First QUestion is there an alternative way to get this small "overview" map?
(I've seen them in some Maps-Examples).
Second if there is not an other way, or if this is the only way to be done, how can i change the position of the second map within the first map?

Would appreciate it, if somebody could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [OverviewMapControl](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.1/com/google/gwt/maps/client/control/OverviewMapControl.html)?